# Outlook 2016 has a "Archive" button which moves an email to a specific folder. Is there a keyboard shortcut for that action?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, archiving

Word lets you customize keyboard shortcuts from inside the **Customize Ribbon** preference pane. Outlook seems to lack this feature, but I'm admittedly not an Outlook guru.

Is there a way that I can invoke the **Archive** button using a keyboard shortcut? This is the button I'm referring to:

[image: Outlook 2016 Archive button]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In versions of Outlook pre-2016, this functionality existed in the **Move To:** Quick Step. It was renamed **Archive** in Outlook 2016, and there's a larger button, but it's the same as the old Quick Step.

1. Right click **Archive** in the Quick Step pane (or **Move To** if
   you're using an older version of Outlook
2. Click **Edit Archive** (or **Edit Move To** in older versions of Outlook)
3. Specify a Shortcut key combination from the drop-down

In Outlook 2016, if you hover over the **Archive** button, it tells you that **Backspace** is also a keyboard shortcut. I can't speak for other versions of Outlook.

Comment: Oh, I was unfamiliar with Quick Steps. As it happens, "Move To" has been renamed to "Archive", and indeed you can assign it a keyboard shortcut. Alas, the keyboard shortcuts are limited to Ctrl+Shift+Num, which is a bummer, as Ctrl+Shift is awkward on Kinesis keyboards...

Comment: I edited your answer to include step-by-step instructions for assigning the keyboard shortcuts, and to explain a bit of the UI changes between Outlook versions. (Just in case my comment above looks ridiculous to someone else with the same question. :) )

Comment: Cautionary note: if you're on Outlook 2016 for Mac and using a PC keyboard, the backspace key does **not** Archive the message - it **deletes** it. The correct shortcut on Mac is **CTRL+E**.

Comment: Another cautionary note:  in Outlook 2013 for PC the backspace key also does **not** Archive the message, but **deletes** it.

Answer (score 1):

Archive in the ribbon archives an entire folder.

To set up hotkey archive of individual or groups of emails, right-click an email in your inbox, go to Quick Steps > Create New.  Then you can set up a quick step and select a hotkey combination.